# merge adjacent integers into ranges?

Tags: r

I want to merge adjacent integers into ranges.

For example, suppose the input is the following.

```
R> c(1,2,3, 5,6, 9,10,11,12)
```

The output should be a matrix of the range boundary. The result for the example should be.

```
rbind(
c(1, 3)
, c(5, 6)
, c(9,12)
)
```

How to perform this operation in an efficient way? I suppose that vectorized functions should be called to speed things up, as for-loop, although can solve the problem, is not efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Split at `cumsum` where differences are unequal to `1` and apply `range` using `by` for instance.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12)

do.call(rbind, by(x, cumsum(c(1, diff(x)) != 1), range))
#   [,1] [,2]
# 0    1    3
# 1    5    6
# 2    9   12
```